# Increase size of touch area - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));        
    }
```

With this code I can touch the point on the screen but when I catch my balls on the screen sometimes i can't because they are too fast.

So can i take the point of click and enlarge this point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 2D or 3D Sphere collider and attach it to Empty gameobject , move that game object towards touch points on screen and use OnCollisionEnter2D() or OnCollisionEnter3D() event to detect detections with falling balls. Now the sphere collider is as a whole a point and its radius can altered in inspector to enlarge the points

More about On Collision Event : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped you @Axilex

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Before (Inspector View):

```
BallGameObject
- Rigidbody
- Script that listens to OnMouseDown
```

After (Inspector View):

```
BallGameObject
 - Rigidbody
 - TouchDetectGameObject
   - Circle Collider 2d (**Use a Sphere collider if you're in 3d!)
     - Radius: 5
   - Script that listens to OnMouseDown
```

Basically, **add a child object** with no material so it's invisible and its own Circle Collider + **OnMouse listeners**. Make the **child object bigger than the parent**. With no other changes, I can now click on my Ball even if I'm off to the side a bit with my touch.